# Is there a noun(phrase) meaning 'the state' of being a masterpiece?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, expression-choice, writing-style

'Masterpiece' is a noun. I would like, however, to use a noun or a concise noun phrase which refers not to a masterpiece, but its state of being a masterpiece. I thought of using 'masterpieciness' as a neologism, but I don't know how digestible that would sound.

> For example:
>
> The 'masterpieceness' of the work lies in its . . .

Comment: There are probably plenty of more general terms like *sublimity, magnificence, glory, majesty*, but I doubt there'll be anything so specific as *the state of being a chef-d'oeuvre / artistic paragon*. In your example context, the specific sub-sense is obviously implied anyway, so you certainly wouldn't *need* it there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **mastery**, even though people's primary association is of *a person's mastery of something*. Mastery can still be used for the quality of the thing.

Alternatively, you could try **virtuosity**, which at least covers the "great technical skill" part of *masterpieceness* and functions as a synonym of "mastery."

And two other words that connote *exceptional*, as "masterpiece" does:

**genius**

and

**brilliance**

Both of which refer not only to the quality of the master, but also the qualities the master injects into his/her works.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the noun itself is perfect:

**The masterpiece in the work lies in its...**

Comment: How about "the masterwork in the piece"?  Granted, it points more to the artist, but that seems OK to me. "Masterpiece in the work" sounds as if only part of the work is a masterpiece.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an art-blindness happening with the word "masterpiece" in that it originally was the work a graduating apprentice was expected to make that included all techniques learned and executed at a high level of skill in order to join a guild, i.e. to be acknowledged by peers.

Genius for example, is hackneyed

Perhaps "aura" is taking it to a level beyond that in terms of an artistic accomplishment, or even "mastery" or "art" itself. The mastery in the work... etc.

Personally I'd go for "the exceptionality in the work lies in its..." – to load on  "masterpiece" is to me, overkill & even tautology.